# How to get 60hz resolution with 3840×2160 on Monitor with HDMI 1.4b or 1920x1080 without blurry picture

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, resolution

I have LG 4K monitor (Model [lg-27UL850-W](https://www.lg.com/in/monitors/lg-27UL850-W)) and Lenovo laptop (S540-15IML Laptop (ideapad) - Type 81NG).

Laptop specification

```
Processor: 1x 10th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-10210U Processor(Core i5-10210U)
Memory: 1x 4GB DDR4 2400 1x 4GBDDR42400
Operating System: Windows 10
Hard Drive 1x 1TB 2.5"5400RPM 1x 256GB NVMe
Wireless Network 1x RealTek Wireless RTL8822CE 1x1 AC & Bluetooth® 5.0
Ports: 1x SD Card reader; HDMI A; DC-in Jack; Audio Jacks; 2 USB 3.0; 1 USB 3.1(Type C)
Camera: 1x 720P HD Fixed Focus with Privacy Shutter
Graphics: 1x NVIDIA MX250
Monitor: 15.6 FHD
```

The laptop has USB-C without video output, and HDMI 1.4b. Hence, only option to connect monitor is HDMI cable.

As per HDMI 1.4b specification, it supports 3840×2160 at 24, 25, and 30 Hz, and 1920×1080 at 120 Hz.

If I choose 3840×2160, I can get max 30hz, which isn't look good on 27 inch monitor. If I go with 1920x1080, I can get max 60hz. But with 1920x1080, I get blurry picture.

I have tried to change multiple resolutions, but nothing works smoothy.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  You say `it supports 3840×2160 at 24, 25, and 30 Hz` and your question is `How to get 60hz resolution with 3840×2160 on Monitor with HDMI 1.4b`.  What gives?  Assuming that your own information is correct.. YOU DON'T.  It is as if you answered your own question.

Comment: Are you sure the USB-C has no video output?

Comment: Technically products are not even allowed to be advrtized with HDMI version numbers. You either support a feature or not. For this to work, you need to use YCbCr 4:2:0 colorspace. But both your monitor and PC need to support it. 4k30 in 4:4:4 or 4:2:2 uses same bandwith as 4k60 in 4:2:0.

Comment: to get 4k60 on HDMI 1.4 you would need to be able to select 4:2:0 YCBCR: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Refresh_frequency_limits_for_standard_video

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Your comment make sense! I have asked if there any work around like dongle solution.

Comment: @FluidCode Yes, it only supports data transfer, no video output, no charging

Comment: @Mokubai I have found [this option](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/images/graphics/57255-img1.png) in intel control panel, but how to set 4:2:0?

Comment: @Div does your laptop have an extra graphic card or is it using the integrated graphic of the chipset? You probably have to check the output capability of your laptop (and graphic card) as per factory specs. Strange that you could not set an intermediate resolution at higher frequency, between 1920×1080 and 3840×2160 there are a lot of other possible settings.

Comment: @FluidCode Yes, my laptop has [graphic card NVIDIA GeForce MX250](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvJbg.png). I can set other resolutions in between as well, but it seems not use the monitor screen fully.

Comment: @div sometimes when only part of the monitor area is covered you can fix it via the OSD (on screen display), but you will lose a little bit o image quality. If your laptop cannot output a high resolution at a high frame rate you'll have to go through harder options, either upgrade the graphic firmware or play with the monitor settings.